# cPanel CGI default page redirect

Tags: cpanel

For some reason when I try to access my website with .com it redirects to default CGI page
I checked and account is created and it is under /home/.

If I try to go to page via IP like 192.168.0.100/~ it works.

Only problem is that I can't access it with domain.

Account is new and it is not terminated but still I get page SORRY! Webpage not available /cgi default webpage.

Does anybody knows how can I fix this.

BTW. I am on dedicated root server and for now this is the only account on the server woth package without limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I can see there is an issues with your DNS setup. Please update your correct nameserver and point your site to correct IP which is assigned your account on your server.

Answer (score 0):

This default page can be show on miss config of dns of that domain,

or it may be due to cookies issue your dns is redirecting you to default cgi etc.,

some time your domain propagation has been done, whenever it show default page. so thry to acces complete address like `domainname.com/index.php` or  `www.domainname.com/index.php`

other way you can try this to open on a proxy like `http://anonymouse.org/anonwww.html`